# ¿ como puedo desplegar mi aplicacion de node en windose server 2019? (MERN Stack)

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, server

tengo un problema.

cree una aplicación web para uso interno de una red estoy usando react para el front-end y en el back-end estoy usando node con express y mongoDB. el front-end ya esta desplegado, pero ahora necesito subir la aplicación con el node y no pude encontrar información que me ayude a subirlo al servidor y que me permita accesos remotos para cualquier consulta a la base.

Comment: usas IIS o Apache en tu servidor?

Comment: IIS -> https://medium.com/@mr.dominguez/instalando-y-ejecutando-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-node-js-en-iis-de-windows-server-7a9fe419bdc6

Comment: Apache -> https://medium.com/@chamiperera95/how-to-run-node-js-server-and-apache-server-together-ee225ece6a44

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.